# How to resize all contents of a window in PyQt5 in Python?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have designed a GUI program using python PyQt5. Since I have designed it on my PC, everything is running well. But when i run the GUI on my Laptop, I have screen size problem and about 10% of the GUI window is not show on laptop desktop because the height and width are more than the height and width of laptop screen.
Is there any way to make my GUI resizable in such a way that when i resize the window, all of its contents such as buttons, labels, Qtextedit, textboxes and etc. get resize such that they again fit inside the new window?
I really appreciate answers which solve my problem.

Comment: You have layouts in PyQt5, `QGridLayout`, `QHBoxLayout`, `QVBoxLayout`, etc. By putting the widgets in the layouts, they can be resized with respect to the size of the main window.

Comment: Use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), [also if you're using Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for your reply. I have used layouts such as QGridLayout, after that should i write any code to make it resizeable?

Comment: @Orca Did you actually set a main layout for the window (or the central widget, if you're using a QMainWindow)? If you're using Designer, carefully follow what explained in the second link above; if you're creating the UI by code, ensure that you are actually setting the layout (and remember that you cannot set a layout on a QMainWindow, you must do it on its central widget).

Comment: @musicamante Thank you very much. I will  study the link you mentioned in comments